# How to turn txt file to nice dataframe

Tags: r, text-mining

I have a txt file containing Track ID, Song ID, Artist Name and Song name. I'd like to convert it into a dataframe in R to do some analysis. What would be a good function to use to separate the data? Below is the top row of the dataset. Thanks!

```
TRMMMKD128F425225D<SEP>SOVFVAK12A8C1350D9<SEP>Karkkiautomaatti<SEP>Tanssi vaan
```

Comment: where does the trackID ends and song id starts

Comment: Updated the sample row. Different variables are separated by the "<sep>" in the row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `read.table` to directly read the file as a dataframe but separator (`sep`) between columns can be of only one character.

So we can first use `readLines` to read the text file, replace `'<SEP>'` using `gsub` with a single character (`'\t'`) and then use `read.table` specifying column names.

```
data <- read.table(text = gsub('<SEP>', '\t', 
         readLines('filename.txt'), fixed = TRUE), 
         col.names = c('TrackID', 'SongID', 'ArtistName', 'SongName'),sep = "\t")
data

#             TrackID             SongID       ArtistName    SongName
#1 TRMMMKD128F425225D SOVFVAK12A8C1350D9 Karkkiautomaatti Tanssi vaan
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `separate`

```
library(tidyr)
separate(df1, 'Col1', into = c('TrackID', 'SongID', 'ArtistName', 'SongName'),

         "\\<SEP\\>")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `readLines` and `strsplit`.

```
rw <- readLines("X:/foo.txt")
nice.df <- setNames(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(rw, "<SEP>"))),
                    c("Track.ID", "Song.ID", "Artist.Name", "Song.name"))
nice.df
#             Track.ID            Song.ID      Artist.Name   Song.name
# 1 TRMMMKD128F425225D SOVFVAK12A8C1350D9 Karkkiautomaatti Tanssi vaan
# 2 TRMMMKD128F425225D SOVFVAK12A8C1350D9 Karkkiautomaatti Tanssi vaan
# 3 TRMMMKD128F425225D SOVFVAK12A8C1350D9 Karkkiautomaatti Tanssi vaan
# 4 TRMMMKD128F425225D SOVFVAK12A8C1350D9 Karkkiautomaatti Tanssi vaan
```

---

*foo.txt content:*

```
TRMMMKD128F425225D<SEP>SOVFVAK12A8C1350D9<SEP>Karkkiautomaatti<SEP>Tanssi vaan
TRMMMKD128F425225D<SEP>SOVFVAK12A8C1350D9<SEP>Karkkiautomaatti<SEP>Tanssi vaan
TRMMMKD128F425225D<SEP>SOVFVAK12A8C1350D9<SEP>Karkkiautomaatti<SEP>Tanssi vaan
TRMMMKD128F425225D<SEP>SOVFVAK12A8C1350D9<SEP>Karkkiautomaatti<SEP>Tanssi vaan
```